# TikZ Matrix Alignment Issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes={minimum height=3em, draw, anchor=center}] {
    foo & fooy\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result:
[image]
I would like to align the cell boxes properly. The only solution I know for this is to add `anchor=center` to the node style, i.e.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes={minimum height=3em, draw, anchor=center}] {
    foo & fooy\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this results in misaligned text (red guideline is for visualization purposes and is not part of the MWE):
[image]

How can I align both the text and the cell boxes in the intended way?

Comment: Add `\strut` before or after `foo`: `foo\strut`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [TikZ manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf), in the "Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs", the key is to directly fix the height and depth of the nodes. That way, you force them to be aligned. The key words are `text height` and `text depth`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (A)% 
    [matrix of nodes, 
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes=
        {minimum height=3em, 
        draw, 
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=.25ex,
        anchor=center}
    ] {
    foo & fooy\\
    };

    \draw[red, very thin] (A-1-1.base) -- +(1.5,0);
    \draw[blue, very thin] (A-1-2.base) -- +(-1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the left side of the picture, you can see the result when those keys are not specified, I place them side by side and draw the lines on the base for comparison

[image: Solution comparison with previous picture]

Answer (score 2):

If you're ever dealing with text that may have varying height/depth, you can use `\strut` to ensure similar depth/height. Here's an example with `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{foo}\ \fbox{fooy}

\fbox{\strut foo}\ \fbox{\strut fooy}

\end{document}
```

In a similar vein, issue `\strut` with the components you want to have similar height/depth (no guessing required):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (A) 
    [matrix of nodes, 
    column sep = -\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep = -\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes = {
      minimum height=3em, 
      draw, 
      anchor = center
    }] {
    \strut foo & \strut fooy \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add key `text depth=.25ex` inside nodes options

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (A) [%
  matrix of nodes,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={minimum height=3em, draw, text depth=.25ex, anchor=center}
  ]
  {
    foo & fooy\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need the matrix cells squared, you can use the code below

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=3em,
      anchor=center,
      text width=3em,
      text depth=.25ex,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
  {
    foo & fooy\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `text depth` is sometimes not enough. You have to add `text height` as well.